# Getting command to be read multiple times c#

Tags: c#, winforms, input, command

I am making a programming, using c# winforms, which in effect is a very simple programming language which allows users to enter commands e.g. circle(radius), rectangle(width,height), triangle(side,side,side), moveTo(x,y) <- to move the pos of the pen. The problem i am having is that the program is only reading one command at a time and not taking all the commands and executing them as a block.

I want to be able to put a list of commands and the program then execute that list e.g. moveTo(x,y) circle(radius) <- this would draw a circle on the screen with a radius and wherever the user defined the x and y pos.

```
public void RunProgram()
    {
        try
        {
            string[] spilt = cp.UserCMD(textInput).Split('(', ')', ',');
            foreach (string cmd in spilt) //spilt string on brackets and comma 
            {
                if (cp.ValidCommand(textInput) == true)
                {
                    if (cp.FunctionCMD(textInput) == "reset")
                    {
                        x = 0;
                        y = 0;
                    }
                    else if (cp.FunctionCMD(textInput) == "moveTo")
                    {
                        x = Int32.Parse(spilt[1]);
                        y = Int32.Parse(spilt[2]);

                    }
                }

                if (cp.FunctionCMD(textInput) == "circle")
                {
                    radius = Int32.Parse(spilt[1]);
                }
                if (cp.FunctionCMD(textInput) == "rectangle")
                {
                    width = Int32.Parse(spilt[1]);
                    height = Int32.Parse(spilt[2]);
                }
                if (cp.FunctionCMD(textInput) == "triangle")
                {
                    side1 = Int32.Parse(spilt[1]);
                    side2 = Int32.Parse(spilt[2]);
                    side3 = Int32.Parse(spilt[3]);

                }

            }

            Graphics g;
            g = Graphics.FromImage(drawOutput);
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 5);

            if (cp.ValidCommand(textInput) == true)
            {
                if (cp.FunctionCMD(textInput) == "circle")
                {
                    circle.drawCircle(radius, pen, g, x, y);
                    setImage(g);

                }
                if (cp.FunctionCMD(textInput) == "rectangle")
                {
                    rect.drawRectangle(width, height, pen, g, x, y);
                    setImage(g);
                }
                if (cp.FunctionCMD(textInput) == "triangle")
                {
                    tri.drawTriangle(side1, side2, side3, pen, g);
                    setImage(g);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have a syntax error, Please check your command");
            }
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have a syntax error, Please check your parameters \nError: \n" + e1);
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you step through the code with your debugger and observe the value of variables along the way?  You should be able to easily troubleshoot what's happening in such a simple scenario.

Comment: You need to learn about top-down programming and breaking the goal into smaller units with nice names. Your one block of code is a dead-end!

Comment: I will try this and get back to you. I am new to programming with winforms

Comment: @TaW how would you suggest i do this

Comment: By using functions.

Comment: i tried to spilt that big chunk of code into functions with not much success unfortunately @Marceline

Comment: Based on what I see here (using a radius, x, y, etc. whose declaration/instantiation(s) aren't shown) you're likely to run into issues trying to complete this. What happens if I want to draw 2 circles and 3 rectangles?

Comment: @user12309785 You can give commands to select and add the selected commands in listbox, then loop though all the items in listbox thats it.